# How to automate facebook api with selenium web driver?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please help me with the tools for automating the facebook api using selenium web driver.

I tried in google and other locations, but did not get any.

If you tried already facebook api automation, please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is only for automating web browsers and websites, not for automating webservice APIs.  For automation of webservices, whether restful or SOAP, for that you should use SoapUI or JMeter .